# Why can't Cloud Function access metadata server in Vertex AI example?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-iam, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I followed [this Vertex AI  tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/image-recognition-custom/serving). However, at the last step, as the Cloud Function calls the prediction endpoint, it gets this failure.

This means it could not even  access the metadata server. I.e., is not a permissions failure (though I did check that the `myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account does have Project Editor role as specified). It is also an error strictly in  Functions and IAM, not in Vertex.AI or other ML systems.

What is going wrong here?

```
Function execution took 673 ms, finished with status code: 500
Prediction request failed: <class 'google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable'>: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 500 Response:\nb'Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform\\n'", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x3e095a9f4c50>)
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 500 Response:\nb'Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform\\n'", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x3e095a9f4c50>)
 File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
   six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 117, in refresh
   self.refresh(request)
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
   self._request, context.method_name, context.service_url, headers
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 88, in _get_authorization_headers
   callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 101, in __call__
   context, _AuthMetadataPluginCallback(callback_state, callback))
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 78, in __call__
Traceback (most recent call last):

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 500 Response:\nb'Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform\\n'", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x3e095a9f4c50>)
   response,
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 187, in get
   token_json = get(request, path, params=params)
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 263, in get_service_account_token
   request, service_account=self._service_account_email, scopes=scopes
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 113, in refresh
Traceback (most recent call last):
AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x3e0961671dd0>" raised exception!
```

Comment: Did you try several time? It might be a transient error. Can you also share the region where you deploy your Cloud Functions?

Comment: I clicked on a flower for prediction about ten times, 2 hours ago. I left the system running. Just now I tried again,  with the same outcome. The region is us-central1

Comment: Can you try to update the `google-cloud-aiplatform` dependency to `google-cloud-aiplatform=1.1.1` then deploy and try again.

Comment: I guess you mean `aiplatform=1.1.1 `, right?  I did that -- same issue

Comment: Can you try with `google-cloud-aiplatform`. I don't find the `aiplatform` on pypi!

Comment: My mistake. I was using `google-cloud-aiplatform==1.1.1` as of my last report, in which the failure occurred again

Comment: I was ale to follow the tutorial and get the predictions. Could you start it again and check if you get the same error?

Comment: Thank you. I redeployed and go the same error about being unable  to access the metadata server. The message indicates that this is apparently a bug in Functions and IAM, not in the AI systems. It is puzzling, because a Function should always be able to access the metadata server.

Comment: As of now, I would suggest you  to file an issue in Google's [Issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: Done https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192577226

Comment: After waiting a month and a third try, the problem did not recur. I still think it was a real problem when reported -- perhaps some temporary failure of the metadata-server infrastructure (even though it lasted a full day)